# Currency format in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Am trying to format my number format of gridview to currency format. But its not getting converted and the number appears as it is. Here is my code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nov" SortExpression="November">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Nov", "{0:#,0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Nov", "{0:#,0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headergrid11" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have replaced "{0:#,0}" with examples like "{0:c}", etc also. but its not working. Kindly help to solve this. Gridview column is converted to template field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Nov` is **not** type of `string` you can replace

```
<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nov", "{0:#,0}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

with

```
<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nov", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

because a `Label` can't be used to edit data.